# Using MouseListener's mouseEntered method for multiple buttons/JLabels

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, mouselistener

I have a panel with 6 JButtons and an empty JLabel on the bottom. I want the JLabel to display a description of whichever button I hover over with the mouse through mouseEntered() method.

Is there any sort of method equivalent to getActionCommand() for MouseEvent? I figure if the program is able see which button's string I'm hovering over then I'll be able to change the JLabel.

Edit:
If there is no equivalent method, which doesn't seem to be from what I understand from the docs, is there a way I can use the mouseEntered method for multiple buttons?

Comment: The Javadoc for the MouseEvent interface: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/events/MouseEvent.html

Comment: I've read it and I know what a MouseEvent is. It doesn't really help with my particular situation though.

Comment: The EventTarget getRelatedTarget() method of a MouseEvent seems promising.  I don't have a test application, though you do.

Comment: I figured it out. I could've used getSource to specify which button it's hovering over. Thank you for taking time to help though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I can use getSource to specify which button it's hovering over. Pretty much does exactly what I want it to do.